# can't download numpy in cmd

Tags: python, numpy, cmd

When I try to download numpy it doesn't work.

a tutorial told me to move directories to `c:\` but it didn't make any difference.
this is the error:

```
C:\>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)'))) - skipping
```

does anyone know why it does this?

Comment: It's likely you'll need to upgrade pip. It's then also likely `pip install --upgrade pip` won't work (with the same error), so you may have to download a more recent version of pip. What version of Python are you using? Recent versions of Python have more recent versions pip shipped with it.

Comment: @9769953 your right it did do the same thing. but i downloaded python relatively recently. i have python 3.7.1

Comment: And what does `pip --version` give you? It that is also recent, then the suggestions in the answers may be more applicable.

Comment: @9769953 yeah it's pip 18.1. is that recent?

Comment: It is recent enough that it looks like my hunch was incorrect: pip is very likely *not* the problem here. It is likely somewhere in your system environment, but hard to see where.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is because of your network SSL certificate issue. If you are using corporate network, you can try a different one.

Comment: how can i fix my SSL certificate if that is the problem?

Comment: @BOBTHEBUILDER Probably try another WiFi

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check if you are not behind some sort of proxy that intercept your HTTPS traffic.

But even if the case, you have a way to install numpy without asking pip to download it on the fly: Try download a "wheel" package from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ for your Windows CPython version and install with `pip install c:\path\to\mypackage.whl`